# ABP vs Asp.net Boilerplate - Current State for Production

Tags: abp

I am about to embark on a few multi-tenant applications projects and are seriously looking at both ABP and ASP.NET Boilerplate as a starting point. Since I have that rare chance to start anew, I would like to obviously go with the latest and greatest (ABP) but it seems that ABP is missing LOTS of documentation - event system, emailing, how to seed data, etc - everywhere I go I see TO DO in the documentation and that makes me question how many people are developing new projects with it. 
Are people (that previously had not developed a ASP.NET Boilerplate solution) actually using ABP? 
How are you resolving all the documentation holes? 
With such a better foundation in place, what are the real downsides of going with ASP.NET Boilerplate?

Thanks, Dave

Answer (score 4):

I have had some Experience with Boilerplate frameworks like ABP and DNN etc.. In my Experience the short term gains of using these monolithic frameworks are not worth the cost they incur later on in the solutions lifetime.

If you are making an application that you are not planning on maintaining later on, then by all means these sorts of solutions are perfectly fine.

However they end up bogged down with too much dead weight.

If you have a decent timeline and a proper concept to follow, then a stand alone solution is best.

Comment: the framework itself focuses much in the Web layer (some kind of gateway), there are many components you need to write yourself if not using the framework including: caching, validation, data access, authorization... They may cost one developer a month or more to complete a basic usable code base to develop on. Also when it comes to a team, making familiar with code of another member (usually the leader) can be challenging (because of the code quality, lack of documentation ...) to other members. So using a framework in such a case may be a good choice...

Comment: for the purpose of scaling the app, I believe that it almost lies in the under layer (not the web layer), more specifically the service layer - which can be run in multiple independent hosts. Even the gateway can be scaled. All the components I mentioned above are usually put in one monolithic because they belong to the gateway layer. So the web framework here is monolithic but it's not the whole solution and of course completely fine to use even it's required to be scalable and modular.

Answer (score 3):

I had the oportunity to use ASP.NET BOILERPLATE with net framework last year january, and then (10 months ago) in a net core project.
Then a new net core project came 5 months ago and we were eskeptical about ABP madurity, but instead we jumped to it because it was recommended for net core, despite most of the documentation was empty.
It was a good decision, if you have used ASP.NET BOILERPLATE before, or you're starting a net core project, I highly recommend to start with APB framework (they're optimizing a lot for net core). Each week they release new documentation, version's releases very quickly and their github issues page has a lot of documentation from other users' questions (community is rapidly increasing).